# bootstrap side navigation appears open without clicking the button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

HTML fragment:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav"> 
  <div class="container"> <div class="navbar-header" style="left: 80%;"> 
    <a class="navbar-toggle slide-active"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slide-nav.navbar .container').append($('<div id="navbar-height-col"></div>'));
    var toggler = '.navbar-toggle';
    var pagewrapper = '#page-content';
    var navigationwrapper = '.navbar-header';
    var menuwidth = '100%'; 
    var slidewidth = '80%';
    var menuneg = '-100%';
    var slideneg = '-80%';
    $("#slide-nav").on("click", toggler, function (e) {


        var selected = $(this).hasClass('slide-active');
        $('#slidemenu').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? menuneg : '0px'
        });
        $('#navbar-height-col').stop().animate({
            left: selected ? slideneg : '0px'
        });
        $(pagewrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });
        $(navigationwrapper).stop().animate({
            left: selected ? '0px' : slidewidth
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('slide-active', !selected);
        $('#slidemenu').toggleClass('slide-active');
        $('#page-content, .navbar, body, .navbar-header').toggleClass('slide-active');
    });
    var selected = '#slidemenu, #page-content, body, .navbar, .navbar-header';
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 767 && $('.navbar-toggle').is(':hidden')) {
            $(selected).removeClass('slide-active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I want it to be default close..

Comment: it would be useful to post the HTML

Comment: I want the side navigation to be close as default. after clicking button it should slide on the right. vice versa

Comment: <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="slide-nav">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header" style="left: 80%;">
      <a class="navbar-toggle slide-active"> 
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

Comment: since it is not possible to reproduce, I would say to remove the class 'slide-active' from the html

Comment: i removed active class.its working on the second or third click. but always open.

Comment: you have to post all the code necessary to reproduce your problem, if not it is impossible to fix it, that is valid for every stackoverflow question